# DateTimeZone command stopped working when I switched to virtual server

Tags: php

I used the following PHP code in shared hosting and it worked just fine:

```
$tzFrom = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
```

Now I am trying to use the same code on a virtual server and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DateTimeZone' not found in /var/www/vhosts/...com/httpdocs/.../footer10.php on line 69
```

Any idea why it's not working on the virtual server?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTimeZone`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php) was introduced with PHP 5.2. Your Virtual Server is likely running a previous version. Check the PHP version on the server and upgrade PHP on the server.

Note that support for PHP 5.2 ended on Dec, 9th, 2010. All users of PHP 5.2 are encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.3. To prepare for upgrading to PHP 5.3, now that PHP 5.2's support ended, a migration guide available on http://php.net/migration53, details the changes between PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3.

Comment: No idea, just upload a file with [`<?php phpinfo() ?>`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) or [`<?php echo phpversion() ?>`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) somewhere, check the version and remove the file again.

Comment: @Gordon, thanks.  Any idea how I can upgrade to PHP 5.3 using Plesk?

Comment: @John sorry, cant help with anything Plesk. Maybe you can ask on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) or [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). Or ask here and we will likely move it to the appropriate place then.

Comment: @Gordon: another question: how did you know that DateTimeZone was new for PHP 5.2?

Comment: @John each function in the PHP Manual lists at which version it was introduced to PHP right below the title. See http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php. See where it says *(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)*

Answer (score 1):

Run this code to check your PHP Version:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you are using PHP < 5.2 than DateTimeZone ist not available.